# Get NSBundle in release mode

Tags: ios

I'm new in iOS Programming and I need help with a problem.

If edit scheme to run in release configuration when I access to mainBundle function of NSBundle, this function return nil.

In debug mode working properly.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
```

Thanks

---

**UPDATE**

I've found the problem, in release mode every log prints to nil but work properly.

I'm a Net developer and in Visual Studio this work different.

Thanks

Comment: There is another problem, more information is needed. Reading from the bundle is allowed, writing to it is not.

Comment: I create new project and in ViewController.m add this line, in debug mode work and in release mode, editing scheme return nil.

Comment: From the docs: "Be sure to check the return value to make sure you have a valid bundle.".

Comment: How make sure? I only change from debug to release mode?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today.

Turned out it is to do with **Optimzation Level** for release mode. If you change the build settings to `None` (no optimisation), then it will be working as expected.

Wrote a post on the pitfall: http://samwize.com/2015/03/03/pitfall-release-scheme-optimizes-code/